# Transform 2D Mat object into 1D array

Tags: java, android, opencv

I would like to transform a mat object m2 which size is 100x100 to a double row array like:

```
double[] matrizvector=new double[10000];

int mm=0;
for (int nr=0; nr<100; nr++){ 
    for (int nc=0; nc<100; nc++){ 
        matrizvector[mm]=m2.get(nr,nc)[0];
        mm=mm+1;
    }
}
```

Is there other way to do it, for example using reshape?

Comment: As you are using a custom for loop to achieve this task, and this is the most optimal way of doing this so why you need an other way?

Comment: You can transform an AxB matrix into a 1x(A*B) matrix using reshape: `n = m.reshape(1, 1);` - however, this leaves you with a new matrix object and not a native double array.

Comment: Hi Thanks Ali and Niko... ALi answer: I didn't know it was the optimal way of doing that... I thought It could be a quicker way... I am starting using opencv....

Comment: but is not possible to convert a matrix object to double array?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a combination of [reshape](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#mat-reshape) and [convertTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#void%20Mat%3a%3aconvertTo%28OutputArray%20m,%20int%20rtype,%20double%20alpha,%20double%20beta%29%20const) functions:

```
Mat reshaped = m2.reshape(1,1);
Mat reshapedInDouble;
reshaped.convertTo(reshapedInDouble, CV_64F);

double* matrixzvector = (double*)(reshapedInDouble.data);
```

If your original matrix is already a matrix of double, you dont need to use convertTo.

Comment: Hi, the 3th line is good using CvType (openCV for Android). But the 4th line I think is not possible for Android isn't it?            Mat reshaped = m2.reshape(1,1);
Mat reshapedInDouble=new Mat();
reshaped.convertTo(reshapedInDouble, CvType.CV_64F);

Comment: I dont know the android interface, but the purpose of the 4th line is just to get the pointer to the beginning of the data. In C++, this is given by the field Mat.data, which is unsigned char by default, that's why you need the (double*) casting.